# byte representation in BINARY_CHECKSUM()?

Tags: sql-server

according to this article

> http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/05/18/checksum-functions-in-sql-server-2005/

they say that

> BINARY_CHECKSUM() returns the same value if the elements of two
>   expressions have the same type and **byte representation**. So, “2Volvo
>   Director 20″ and “3Volvo Director 30″ will yield the **same** value

my question is what is `byte representation`?

and why

```
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('2Volvo Director 20'  )// -1356512636
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('3Volvo Director 30'  )// -1356512636
```

gives the same results ?

the byte of '**2**' is **not** as the byte of '**3**'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know exactly what that article means by that phrasing, but from googling around I see that a SQL Server MVP has reverse-engineered the full algorithm (eg [here](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.ms-sqlserver/msg/fbf6544b1428cd78?hl=en)) and others have noticed that the algorithm has weird problems around a 16-character cycle. Notice that in that sample, the changes occur at position 1 and position 17:

```
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('2Volvo Director 20'  )-- -1356512636
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('3Volvo Director 30'  )-- -1356512636
--                      12345678901234567
```

which are 16 apart - if the space is removed so the changes occur at positions 1 and **16**, you get different checksums:

```
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('2Volvo Director20'  )-- 1257395465
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('3Volvo Director30'  )-- 1257395480
--                      12345678901234567
```

The internet consensus appears to be that the hash function offered by `BINARY_CHECKSUM` is of low quality, and that you should use `HASHBYTES` in preference.

Comment: so...why they invented this if its not accurate ? or have some black holes in it ( the 16' cycle...)

Comment: We all make mistakes, even Microsoft :) In particular, coming up with good hash functions is extremely hard, whereas coming up with bad hash functions is extremely easy. At least [the docs for `CHECKSUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) say (basically) "don't use it".

Comment: SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('fa')
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM('dA')
both yield same values... 1537